# File Upload with Functional Webflux

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web, spring-webflux

I'm prototyping the migration to the functional variant of Spring WebFlux (and Spring Boot) using the "Router Kotlin DSL". Now I need some hint for file upload with MIME type `multipart/form-data` instead of e.g. `PUT`ing some data with `application/json`.

When I define a simple router function and a handler like this I get the stacktrace below:

```
fun routes(handler: MultimediaHandler) = router {
    (accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) and "/multimedia").nest {
        PUT("/{id}", handler::upload)
    }
}
class MultimediaHandler {
    fun upload(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        val id = request.pathVariable("id")
        return noContent().build()
    }
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
13:43:29.713 ERROR [i.u.request] [XNIO-1 I/O-3] UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ PUT /multimedia/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000
001 request {Connection=[Keep-Alive], Accept-Encoding=[gzip,deflate], Content-Length=[1672], Content-Type=[multipart/form-data; boundary=-mJAzUqZoGk2nc
N1Rch4O4-KGbTExkAmQ7A], User-Agent=[Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_144)], Host=[localhost:8444]} response {}}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart HttpMessageReader.
        at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.lambda$initMultipartData$3(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:144) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.initMultipartData(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:144) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.<init>(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.createExchange(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:156) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.UndertowHttpHandlerAdapter.handleRequest(UndertowHttpHandlerAdapter.java:71) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:332) [undertow-core-1.4.19.Final.jar:1.4.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:254) [undertow-core-1.4.19.Final.jar:1.4.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136) [undertow-core-1.4.19.Final.jar:1.4.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:148) [undertow-core-1.4.19.Final.jar:1.4.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.AlpnOpenListener$AlpnConnectionListener.handleEvent(AlpnOpenListener.java:357) [undertow-core-1.4.19.Final.jar:1.4.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.AlpnOpenListener$AlpnConnectionListener.handleEvent(AlpnOpenListener.java:308) [undertow-core-1.4.19.Final.jar:1.4.19.Final]
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92) [xnio-api-3.5.1.Final.jar:3.5.1.Final]
        at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66) [xnio-api-3.5.1.Final.jar:3.5.1.Final]
        at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1140) [undertow-core-1.4.19.Final.jar:1.4.19.Final]
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89) [xnio-nio-3.5.1.Final.jar:3.5.1.Final]
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:571) [xnio-nio-3.5.1.Final.jar:3.5.1.Final]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the following dependency on your classpath?
Spring Framework requires this for parsing multipart requests.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.synchronoss.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>nio-multipart-parser</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, now the error is gone. FYI, as long as I was using Spring Cloud and Spring Boot with Spring MVC this dependency was not required. I just used MultipartFile with @RequestParam.

Comment: That's because it's using standard servlet multipart support. Here there's no such thing.